# Display single row from dataset across multiple fields in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to create a SSRS report that displays data as shown below--**each block of 3 is a single row in the dataset**.  I've tried using the tablix and matrix controls to achieve this display but so far have been unsuccessful. I'd greatly appreciate advice on how to design this.

## Referral Id: **1**

| Disposition Id: **1** | Created By: **John Doe** | Created Date: **05-05-2016** |

---

---

| Cause Number: **84** | County: **King** | Prosecutor: **Mary Smith** |

---

---

| Restitution Requested: **$1000** | Awarded: **$800** | Paid: **$800** |

---

---

| Disposition Id: **2** | Created By: **Joe Blow** | Created Date: **07-05-2016** |

---

---

| Cause Number: **55** | County: **Pierce** | Prosecutor: **Susan Johnson** |

---

---

| Restitution Requested: **$2000** | Awarded: **$1500** | Paid: **$1000** |

---

---

| Disposition Id: **3** | Created By: **Mia Jones** | Created Date: **09-08-2016** |

---

---

| Cause Number: **62** | County: **Thurston** | Prosecutor: **Ron Sanders** |

---

---

| Restitution Requested: **$1500** | Awarded: **$1500** | Paid: **$1500** |

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a row group in the table that is grouped by the Disposition ID. Then you can put all the text in the cells in those rows. The set of three rows will repeat for each ID. Here's an example of what the basic table structure should look like:
[image]